# Vim - Syntax Highlighting - Javascript - string and boolean same color

Tags: javascript, python, vim, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that `string` and `boolean` syntax are both highlighted the same in javascript, no matter what color scheme I choose.

Is there a way to change it so `boolean` shows up the same color as `const`? I installed https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax which has a syntax/ folder, but I don't know if this is where I am supposed to edit things to change their color.

In `python` `boolean` and `string` are different colors, so if someone could point me where to look to replicate that, that'd work too.

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin that you're linking to, booleans are linked to the `Boolean` highlight group, and `const` is linked to the `Keyword` highlight group ([here](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax/blob/490a0fbb7cc336630bf5a8759c2a774dcacf22f4/syntax/javascript.vim#L245) and [here](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax/blob/490a0fbb7cc336630bf5a8759c2a774dcacf22f4/syntax/javascript.vim#L242)).

You can create a link from the former to the latter, which would make booleans look similar to keywords:

```
# ~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
hi link Boolean Keyword
```

To give booleans their own color, you can use something like this:

```
# ~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
hi Boolean ctermfg=Green
```

More info [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight).